# How to vary the line color of a matlab plot (like colormap)?

Tags: matlab, colors, plot

I have a 2D space in which a function value is defined (you can think of it as a manifold). Now I plotted the function value using contourf and changed the colormap to something softer than jet. So far it looks quite good.

Now I want to draw a line representing the state over time in my space. That is also possible using the the `plot` command. But I want some more improvements: There is an additional state that is hidden for now (value 0...50). I would like the line color to change according to this hidden state. So in a sense to apply a separate colormap to the line plotted by `plot` like for example in a waterfall plot.

Is this (or something similar) possible using matlab?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look into the [cline.m](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3747-cline-m) function from file exchange, I think it is exactly what you need.

Comment: This will do what you want, assuming you want flat shading. It's also not pretty.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to either use interpolated shading or have the colours change with the colour map, then you want to plot your data as a mesh and set the `edgecolor` property appropriately. Note that in order to plot it as a mesh, then you will need to duplicate it so that it has a size of at least 2 in each direction.

```
h = mesh([X(:) X(:)], [Y(:) Y(:)], [Z(:) Z(:)], [C(:) C(:)], ...
    'EdgeColor', 'interp', 'FaceColor', 'none');
```

You may also want to look at the `MeshStyle` property, if you want to plot multiple lines simultaneously.

This solution is also much nicer than the one used in `cline` because it only creates one graphics object, rather than `n`.

Comment: Im an not sure, if I understand you correctly. I thought the `mesh` commant would produce 3D plots. I want it to be in 2D (projectued from above). What values shold I set for the Z coordinates?

Comment: Set the Z co-ordinate to 0, and use `view(2)` to rotate back to the standard XY viewpoint.

Comment: Also, the function linked to by @Adrian implements exactly this.

Answer (score 2):

I can recommend the [Colored line entry](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19476-colored-line-or-scatter-plot) from the file exchange. It has good feedback and uses the color map to define the displayed colours, I've use it sucessfully on a number of projects.

Comment: As @Nzbuu mentioned, this is prettier than [cline.m](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3747-cline-m), precisely because it uses a single contiguous curve (via [`mesh`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mesh.html)) rather than [`line`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/line.html). That also makes it more efficient if you have many points in your line.