# Color along line in MATLAB polaraxes

Tags: matlab, plot, polar-coordinates

I am trying to combine two "solved" aspects of MATLAB --  1) plotting a 2D line with color that varies along the line in 2) polar axes.

The first part is usually easy, and frequently asked:
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/5042-how-do-i-vary-color-along-a-2d-line or
[How to vary the line color of a matlab plot (like colormap)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559133/how-to-vary-the-line-color-of-a-matlab-plot-like-colormap)

The most commonly suggested trick is to use `surf` or `mesh` to create a "fake" 3D line and color this. However, this is not supported on `polaraxes`in MATLAB:

```
>> polaraxes, hold on;
>> surf([1 1; 1 1], [2 2; 2 2], [3 3; 3 3])
Error using newplot (line 80)
Adding Cartesian plot to polaraxes is not supported.
```

One trick that *does* seem to work is using a sequence of line segments, as is done in `cline.m` from File Exchange. http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3747-cline-m

`>> polaraxes; hold on; cline;`

Gives this

[image: cline polar result]

which is technically what I want... but as pointed out in the previous comments, is much uglier than the solution with surf or mesh since it draws individual segments.

Is there any other way to do this? I found this question also asked here
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/439176-how-do-i-vary-the-color-along-a-line-in-polar-coordinates
with an "accepted answer" that this does not seem possible, so I'm feeling a little pessimistic.

Answer (score 0):

Cross-posting the answer from Chad Greene here
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/822360-color-along-line-in-polaraxes#answer_692780

```
theta = linspace(0,6*pi,100000);
rho1 = theta/10;
polarscatter(theta,rho1,5,rho1,'filled')
```

[image: polarscatter output]

Looks as good as its going to get, I think.

Answer (score 0):

One way to make it "prettier" and not use so few lines is to increase the number of lines that is used to plot the line. I looked into the file of `cline` and where `x` is assigned with 101 points is where you could modify it to get the example to be prettier so that it doesn't look like it is built with straight lines, even if it is so.

So by changing `x=linspace(-10,10,101)` to `x=linspace(-10,10,1001)` the example `polaraxes; hold on; cline;` gets prettier. This means that you could still use `cline` with your own values of `x, y, z, c` and get a pretty polaraxes with your choice of `colormap` if you make the lines small enough, e.g. many points in your interval for `x`.